# Adding vectors to an already populated dataframe

Tags: r

Infrequent R user here, I have a set of CSV files that are already populated with data from another program. There is a requirement to insert a new set of values into this dataframe (calendar_dates) via R.

[Screencap of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SaYH.png)

I'm trying to insert a new `service_id`, `date`, and `exception_type`. My understanding is that R doesn't much care what the data type is, but just to be clear, I have other files that need the same fix, but they require text fields.

I've tried searching on the internet, but all the answers I come across seem to require a much deeper understanding of R than I have. I'm hoping someone can provide an example I can learn from. Tutorial recommendations gratefully accepted. My new entry will simply be `HD,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,20210906,20220102`

Here is a sample file generated via `dput()`:

```
dput(TL_calendar_dates)
structure(list(service_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 
1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 
1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 
1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 
1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 
1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 
1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 
1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1201L, 1201L, 1201L, 1201L, 1201L, 
1201L, 1201L, 1201L, 1201L, 1201L, 1201L, 1201L, 1201L, 1201L, 
1201L, 1201L, 1201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 
152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 
152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 
152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 
152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 
152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 
152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 
152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 
152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 
152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152201L, 152301L, 152301L, 152301L, 
152301L, 152301L, 152301L, 152301L, 152301L, 152301L, 152301L, 
152301L, 152301L, 152301L, 152301L, 152301L, 152301L, 152301L, 
152302L, 152302L, 152302L, 152302L, 152302L, 152302L, 152302L, 
152302L, 152302L, 152302L, 152302L, 152302L, 152302L, 152302L, 
152302L, 152303L, 152303L, 152303L, 152303L, 152303L, 152303L, 
152303L, 152303L, 152303L, 152303L, 152303L, 152303L, 152303L, 
152303L, 152303L, 152303L, 152303L, 152303L, 152303L, 152303L, 
152303L, 152303L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 
155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 
155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 
155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 
155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 
155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 
155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 
155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 
155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 
155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 
155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 
155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 155601L, 
162601L, 162601L, 162601L, 162601L, 162601L, 162601L, 162601L, 
162601L, 162601L, 162601L, 162601L, 162601L, 162601L, 162601L, 
162601L, 162601L, 162601L, 169801L, 169801L, 169801L, 169801L, 
169801L, 169801L, 169801L, 169801L, 169801L, 169801L, 169801L, 
169801L, 169801L, 169801L, 169801L, 169801L, 169801L, 169801L, 
169801L, 1803L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 
1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 
1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 
1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 
1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 
1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 
1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 
1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 1901L, 2L, 2L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 
201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 253403L, 253403L, 253403L, 253403L, 253403L, 
253403L, 253403L, 253403L, 253403L, 253403L, 253403L, 253403L, 
253403L, 253403L, 253403L, 253403L, 253403L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 32501L, 32501L, 32501L, 32501L, 32501L, 32501L, 32501L, 
32501L, 32501L, 32501L, 32501L, 32501L, 32501L, 32501L, 32501L, 
32501L, 32501L, 32603L, 32603L, 32603L, 32603L, 32603L, 32603L, 
32603L, 32603L, 32603L, 32603L, 32603L, 32603L, 32603L, 32603L, 
32603L, 32603L, 32603L, 32603L, 32603L, 32603L, 32603L, 401L, 
401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 
401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 
401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 
401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 
401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 
401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 
401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 
59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 
59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 
59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 
59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 
59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 
59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 
59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59001L, 59101L, 
59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 
59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 
59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 59101L, 62101L, 62101L, 
62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 
62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 
62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 
62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 
62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 
62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 
62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62101L, 62201L, 
62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 
62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 
62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 62201L, 
701L, 701L, 701L, 701L, 701L, 701L, 701L, 701L, 701L, 701L, 701L, 
701L, 701L, 701L, 701L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 
75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 
75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 
75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 
75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 
75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 
75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 
75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75301L, 75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 
75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 
75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 
75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 75401L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 
801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 
801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 
801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 
801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 
801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 
801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L, 801L), date = c(20210906L, 
20211011L, 20211111L, 20210907L, 20210908L, 20210909L, 20210910L, 
20210913L, 20210914L, 20210915L, 20210916L, 20210917L, 20210920L, 
20210921L, 20210922L, 20210923L, 20210924L, 20210927L, 20210928L, 
20210929L, 20210930L, 20211001L, 20211004L, 20211005L, 20211006L, 
20211007L, 20211008L, 20211012L, 20211013L, 20211014L, 20211015L, 
20211018L, 20211019L, 20211020L, 20211021L, 20211022L, 20211025L, 
20211026L, 20211027L, 20211028L, 20211029L, 20211101L, 20211102L, 
20211103L, 20211104L, 20211105L, 20211108L, 20211109L, 20211110L, 
20211112L, 20211115L, 20211116L, 20211117L, 20211118L, 20211119L, 
20211122L, 20211123L, 20211124L, 20211125L, 20211126L, 20211129L, 
20211130L, 20211201L, 20211202L, 20211203L, 20211206L, 20211207L, 
20211208L, 20211209L, 20211210L, 20211213L, 20211214L, 20211215L, 
20211216L, 20211217L, 20210907L, 20210908L, 20210909L, 20210913L, 
20210914L, 20210915L, 20210916L, 20210920L, 20210921L, 20210922L, 
20210923L, 20210927L, 20210928L, 20210929L, 20210930L, 20211004L, 
20211005L, 20211006L, 20211007L, 20211012L, 20211013L, 20211014L, 
20211018L, 20211019L, 20211020L, 20211021L, 20211025L, 20211026L, 
20211027L, 20211028L, 20211101L, 20211102L, 20211103L, 20211104L, 
20211108L, 20211109L, 20211110L, 20211115L, 20211116L, 20211117L, 
20211118L, 20211122L, 20211123L, 20211124L, 20211125L, 20211129L, 
20211130L, 20211201L, 20211202L, 20211206L, 20211207L, 20211208L, 
20211209L, 20211213L, 20211214L, 20211215L, 20211216L, 20211220L, 
20211221L, 20211222L, 20211223L, 20211227L, 20211228L, 20211229L, 
20211230L, 20210910L, 20210917L, 20210924L, 20211001L, 20211008L, 
20211015L, 20211022L, 20211029L, 20211105L, 20211112L, 20211119L, 
20211126L, 20211203L, 20211210L, 20211217L, 20211224L, 20211231L, 
20210907L, 20210908L, 20210909L, 20210913L, 20210914L, 20210915L, 
20210916L, 20210920L, 20210921L, 20210922L, 20210923L, 20210927L, 
20210928L, 20210929L, 20210930L, 20211004L, 20211005L, 20211006L, 
20211007L, 20211012L, 20211013L, 20211014L, 20211018L, 20211019L, 
20211020L, 20211021L, 20211025L, 20211026L, 20211027L, 20211028L, 
20211101L, 20211102L, 20211103L, 20211104L, 20211108L, 20211109L, 
20211110L, 20211115L, 20211116L, 20211117L, 20211118L, 20211122L, 
20211123L, 20211124L, 20211125L, 20211129L, 20211130L, 20211201L, 
20211202L, 20211206L, 20211207L, 20211208L, 20211209L, 20211213L, 
20211214L, 20211215L, 20211216L, 20211220L, 20211221L, 20211222L, 
20211223L, 20211227L, 20211228L, 20211229L, 20211230L, 20210910L, 
20210917L, 20210924L, 20211001L, 20211008L, 20211015L, 20211022L, 
20211029L, 20211105L, 20211112L, 20211119L, 20211126L, 20211203L, 
20211210L, 20211217L, 20211224L, 20211231L, 20210911L, 20210918L, 
20210925L, 20211002L, 20211009L, 20211016L, 20211023L, 20211030L, 
20211106L, 20211113L, 20211120L, 20211127L, 20211204L, 20211211L, 
20211218L, 20210906L, 20210912L, 20210919L, 20210926L, 20211003L, 
20211010L, 20211011L, 20211017L, 20211024L, 20211031L, 20211107L, 
20211111L, 20211114L, 20211121L, 20211128L, 20211205L, 20211212L, 
20211219L, 20211225L, 20211226L, 20220101L, 20220102L, 20210907L, 
20210908L, 20210909L, 20210910L, 20210913L, 20210914L, 20210915L, 
20210916L, 20210917L, 20210920L, 20210921L, 20210922L, 20210923L, 
20210924L, 20210927L, 20210928L, 20210929L, 20210930L, 20211001L, 
20211004L, 20211005L, 20211006L, 20211007L, 20211008L, 20211012L, 
20211013L, 20211014L, 20211015L, 20211018L, 20211019L, 20211020L, 
20211021L, 20211022L, 20211025L, 20211026L, 20211027L, 20211028L, 
20211029L, 20211101L, 20211102L, 20211103L, 20211104L, 20211105L, 
20211108L, 20211109L, 20211110L, 20211112L, 20211115L, 20211116L, 
20211117L, 20211118L, 20211119L, 20211122L, 20211123L, 20211124L, 
20211125L, 20211126L, 20211129L, 20211130L, 20211201L, 20211202L, 
20211203L, 20211206L, 20211207L, 20211208L, 20211209L, 20211210L, 
20211213L, 20211214L, 20211215L, 20211216L, 20211217L, 20211220L, 
20211221L, 20211222L, 20211223L, 20211224L, 20211227L, 20211228L, 
20211229L, 20211230L, 20211231L, 20210910L, 20210917L, 20210924L, 
20211001L, 20211008L, 20211015L, 20211022L, 20211029L, 20211105L, 
20211112L, 20211119L, 20211126L, 20211203L, 20211210L, 20211217L, 
20211224L, 20211231L, 20210910L, 20210917L, 20210924L, 20211001L, 
20211007L, 20211008L, 20211015L, 20211022L, 20211029L, 20211105L, 
20211112L, 20211119L, 20211126L, 20211203L, 20211210L, 20211217L, 
20211223L, 20211224L, 20211231L, 20211010L, 20210907L, 20210909L, 
20210910L, 20210913L, 20210914L, 20210916L, 20210917L, 20210920L, 
20210921L, 20210923L, 20210924L, 20210927L, 20210928L, 20210930L, 
20211001L, 20211004L, 20211005L, 20211007L, 20211008L, 20211012L, 
20211014L, 20211015L, 20211018L, 20211019L, 20211021L, 20211022L, 
20211025L, 20211026L, 20211028L, 20211029L, 20211101L, 20211102L, 
20211104L, 20211105L, 20211108L, 20211109L, 20211112L, 20211115L, 
20211116L, 20211118L, 20211119L, 20211122L, 20211123L, 20211125L, 
20211126L, 20211129L, 20211130L, 20211202L, 20211203L, 20211206L, 
20211207L, 20211209L, 20211210L, 20211213L, 20211214L, 20211216L, 
20211217L, 20211220L, 20211221L, 20211222L, 20211223L, 20211224L, 
20211227L, 20211228L, 20211229L, 20211230L, 20211231L, 20211225L, 
20220101L, 20210908L, 20210915L, 20210922L, 20210929L, 20211006L, 
20211013L, 20211020L, 20211027L, 20211103L, 20211110L, 20211117L, 
20211124L, 20211201L, 20211208L, 20211215L, 20211220L, 20211221L, 
20211222L, 20211223L, 20211224L, 20211227L, 20211228L, 20211229L, 
20211230L, 20211231L, 20210912L, 20210919L, 20210926L, 20211003L, 
20211010L, 20211017L, 20211024L, 20211031L, 20211107L, 20211114L, 
20211121L, 20211128L, 20211205L, 20211212L, 20211219L, 20211226L, 
20220102L, 20210906L, 20211011L, 20211111L, 20211225L, 20211226L, 
20220101L, 20210910L, 20210917L, 20210924L, 20211001L, 20211008L, 
20211015L, 20211022L, 20211029L, 20211105L, 20211112L, 20211119L, 
20211126L, 20211203L, 20211210L, 20211217L, 20211224L, 20211231L, 
20210906L, 20210912L, 20210919L, 20210926L, 20211003L, 20211011L, 
20211017L, 20211024L, 20211031L, 20211107L, 20211111L, 20211114L, 
20211121L, 20211128L, 20211205L, 20211212L, 20211219L, 20211225L, 
20211226L, 20220101L, 20220102L, 20210907L, 20210908L, 20210909L, 
20210910L, 20210913L, 20210914L, 20210915L, 20210916L, 20210917L, 
20210920L, 20210921L, 20210922L, 20210923L, 20210924L, 20210927L, 
20210928L, 20210929L, 20210930L, 20211001L, 20211004L, 20211005L, 
20211006L, 20211007L, 20211008L, 20211012L, 20211013L, 20211014L, 
20211015L, 20211018L, 20211019L, 20211020L, 20211021L, 20211022L, 
20211025L, 20211026L, 20211027L, 20211028L, 20211029L, 20211101L, 
20211102L, 20211103L, 20211104L, 20211105L, 20211108L, 20211109L, 
20211110L, 20211112L, 20211115L, 20211116L, 20211117L, 20211118L, 
20211119L, 20211122L, 20211123L, 20211124L, 20211125L, 20211126L, 
20211129L, 20211130L, 20211201L, 20211202L, 20211203L, 20211206L, 
20211207L, 20211208L, 20211209L, 20211210L, 20211213L, 20211214L, 
20211215L, 20211216L, 20211217L, 20210907L, 20210908L, 20210909L, 
20210910L, 20210914L, 20210915L, 20210916L, 20210917L, 20210921L, 
20210922L, 20210923L, 20210924L, 20210928L, 20210929L, 20210930L, 
20211001L, 20211005L, 20211006L, 20211007L, 20211008L, 20211012L, 
20211013L, 20211014L, 20211015L, 20211019L, 20211020L, 20211021L, 
20211022L, 20211026L, 20211027L, 20211028L, 20211029L, 20211102L, 
20211103L, 20211104L, 20211105L, 20211109L, 20211110L, 20211112L, 
20211116L, 20211117L, 20211118L, 20211119L, 20211123L, 20211124L, 
20211125L, 20211126L, 20211130L, 20211201L, 20211202L, 20211203L, 
20211207L, 20211208L, 20211209L, 20211210L, 20211214L, 20211215L, 
20211216L, 20211217L, 20210913L, 20210920L, 20210927L, 20211004L, 
20211018L, 20211025L, 20211101L, 20211108L, 20211115L, 20211122L, 
20211129L, 20211206L, 20211213L, 20211220L, 20211221L, 20211222L, 
20211223L, 20211224L, 20211227L, 20211228L, 20211229L, 20211230L, 
20211231L, 20210907L, 20210909L, 20210910L, 20210913L, 20210914L, 
20210916L, 20210917L, 20210920L, 20210921L, 20210923L, 20210924L, 
20210927L, 20210928L, 20210930L, 20211001L, 20211004L, 20211005L, 
20211007L, 20211008L, 20211012L, 20211014L, 20211015L, 20211018L, 
20211019L, 20211021L, 20211022L, 20211025L, 20211026L, 20211028L, 
20211029L, 20211101L, 20211102L, 20211104L, 20211105L, 20211108L, 
20211109L, 20211112L, 20211115L, 20211116L, 20211118L, 20211119L, 
20211122L, 20211123L, 20211125L, 20211126L, 20211129L, 20211130L, 
20211202L, 20211203L, 20211206L, 20211207L, 20211209L, 20211210L, 
20211213L, 20211214L, 20211216L, 20211217L, 20210908L, 20210915L, 
20210922L, 20210929L, 20211006L, 20211013L, 20211020L, 20211027L, 
20211103L, 20211110L, 20211117L, 20211124L, 20211201L, 20211208L, 
20211215L, 20211220L, 20211221L, 20211222L, 20211223L, 20211224L, 
20211227L, 20211228L, 20211229L, 20211230L, 20211231L, 20210910L, 
20210917L, 20210924L, 20211001L, 20211008L, 20211015L, 20211022L, 
20211029L, 20211105L, 20211112L, 20211119L, 20211126L, 20211203L, 
20211210L, 20211217L, 20210907L, 20210908L, 20210909L, 20210913L, 
20210914L, 20210915L, 20210916L, 20210920L, 20210921L, 20210922L, 
20210923L, 20210927L, 20210928L, 20210929L, 20210930L, 20211004L, 
20211005L, 20211006L, 20211007L, 20211012L, 20211013L, 20211014L, 
20211018L, 20211019L, 20211020L, 20211021L, 20211025L, 20211026L, 
20211027L, 20211028L, 20211101L, 20211102L, 20211103L, 20211104L, 
20211108L, 20211109L, 20211110L, 20211115L, 20211116L, 20211117L, 
20211118L, 20211122L, 20211123L, 20211124L, 20211125L, 20211129L, 
20211130L, 20211201L, 20211202L, 20211206L, 20211207L, 20211208L, 
20211209L, 20211213L, 20211214L, 20211215L, 20211216L, 20210910L, 
20210917L, 20210924L, 20211001L, 20211008L, 20211015L, 20211022L, 
20211029L, 20211105L, 20211112L, 20211119L, 20211126L, 20211203L, 
20211210L, 20211217L, 20211220L, 20211221L, 20211222L, 20211223L, 
20211224L, 20211227L, 20211228L, 20211229L, 20211230L, 20211231L, 
20210907L, 20210908L, 20210909L, 20210913L, 20210914L, 20210915L, 
20210916L, 20210920L, 20210921L, 20210922L, 20210923L, 20210927L, 
20210928L, 20210929L, 20210930L, 20211004L, 20211005L, 20211006L, 
20211007L, 20211012L, 20211013L, 20211014L, 20211018L, 20211019L, 
20211020L, 20211021L, 20211025L, 20211026L, 20211027L, 20211028L, 
20211101L, 20211102L, 20211103L, 20211104L, 20211108L, 20211109L, 
20211110L, 20211115L, 20211116L, 20211117L, 20211118L, 20211122L, 
20211123L, 20211124L, 20211125L, 20211129L, 20211130L, 20211201L, 
20211202L, 20211206L, 20211207L, 20211208L, 20211209L, 20211213L, 
20211214L, 20211215L, 20211216L, 20211220L, 20211221L, 20211222L, 
20211223L, 20211224L, 20211227L, 20211228L, 20211229L, 20211230L, 
20211231L), exception_type = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-950L))
```

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you want to add to the CSV file, joining columns in R can be as easy as just using cbind(), but it depends on what you want to join and how. It might help to post a reproducible example too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, I thought the screen capture illustrated it. I'm not looking to join columns, just enter new data into an existing structure. Here's a text emaple: service_id,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday,start_date,end_date
1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,20210906,20220102     
101,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20210906,20220102     
1101,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20210906,20220102    and I want to add a new entry like, 1201,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20210906,20220102

Comment: It might be easier if you use dput(), so we can reproduce it on our machine too. E.g. if you stored your table in `obj_name`, it would be `dput(obj_name)`. You can then copy and paste the output here

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned new and infrequent R user with an inherited solution: 
        dput(TL_calendar_dates)
structure(list(service_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L,

Comment: No problem! Hmm, it gets truncated by the comment length, it might be better if you edit your original question with it

Comment: dput() added to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to add a row of data to an already created data.frame, is that correct?

If so, there are several ways to do this.

Based on your data, I created a simple data.frame:

```
TL_calendar_dates <- data.frame(
  service_id = c(1,1,1,101,101,101),
  date = c(20210906, 20211011, 20211111, 20210907, 20210908, 20210909),
  exception_type = c(2,2,2,1,1,1)
)

TL_calendar_dates

service_id     date exception_type
1          1 20210906              2
2          1 20211011              2
3          1 20211111              2
4        101 20210907              1
5        101 20210908              1
6        101 20210909              1
```

Say you have a vector containing data to add to this data.frame:

```
vec <- c(101, 20210916, 3)
```

You can combine them (adding `vec` at the bottom) using `rbind`:

```
rbind(TL_calendar_dates, vec)

  service_id     date exception_type
1          1 20210906              2
2          1 20211011              2
3          1 20211111              2
4        101 20210907              1
5        101 20210908              1
6        101 20210909              1
7        101 20210916              3
```

If you are learning `tidyverse`, there are a couple of additional options.

One, you can use `add_row` from `tibble` and explicitly describe what values go into what columns:

```
library(tidyverse)

add_row(TL_calendar_dates, 
        service_id = 2,
        date = 20210920,
        exception_type = 4)

  service_id     date exception_type
1          1 20210906              2
2          1 20211011              2
3          1 20211111              2
4        101 20210907              1
5        101 20210908              1
6        101 20210909              1
7          2 20210920              4
```

Or you can use `bind_rows` from `dplyr` in a similar way:

```
bind_rows(TL_calendar_dates, 
          c(service_id = 3, date = 20210921, exception_type = 5))

  service_id     date exception_type
1          1 20210906              2
2          1 20211011              2
3          1 20211111              2
4        101 20210907              1
5        101 20210908              1
6        101 20210909              1
7          3 20210921              5
```

Note that for all these examples, you will notice that the rows added are not cumulative. You will need to make sure to assign the result to either the same data.frame or a new data.frame, such as:

```
TL_calendar_dates_NEW <- rbind(TL_calendar_dates, vec)
```

In that way, your result will be stored in the new `TL_calendar_dates_NEW` data.frame.

Comment: Thanks for your time, patience, and mostly, thoroughness. In the end the vector (rbind) solution worked fine for me. I tried the others out as well, but the vector one doesn't require additional libraries so it will be easier for the next person to support (I hope!)